# Native: tried accessing the GoogleMap plugin but it's not installed

Tags: google-maps, ionic2

Trying to implement google maps (native) in ionic 2, tried out various things but all in vain.

**Tried out:**

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-maps-typescript-error-cannot-find-name-google-discussion/49990

**Errors:**

Native: tried accessing the GoogleMap plugin but it's not installed.

Install the GoogleMap plugin: 'ionic plugin add plugin.google.maps.Map'

When trying to install the above plugin it says:

Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/plugin.google.maps.Map

HTML-

```
<ion-content padding>
 <div #map id="map" ></div>
</ion-content>
```

JS -

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent, GoogleMapsLatLng } from 'ionic-native';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-store-map',
  templateUrl: 'store-map.html'
})
export class StoreMapPage {
map: GoogleMap;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public platform: Platform, 
public navParams: NavParams) { 
platform.ready().then(() => {
  alert('Ready');
  this.loadMap();
});
}
 ionViewDidLoad() {
console.log('ionViewDidLoad StoreMapPage');
}

loadMap()
{

    let location = new GoogleMapsLatLng(-34.9290,138.6010);

    this.map = new GoogleMap('map', {
      'backgroundColor': 'white',
      'controls': {
        'compass': true,
        'myLocationButton': true,
        'indoorPicker': true,
        'zoom': true
      },
      'gestures': {
        'scroll': true,
        'tilt': true,
        'rotate': true,
        'zoom': true
      },
      'camera': {
        'latLng': location,
        'tilt': 30,
        'zoom': 15,
        'bearing': 50
      }
    });

    this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).subscribe(() => {
        console.log('Map is ready!');
    });

}

}
```

Can someone help how to go ahead with this?

Answer (score 3):

Got the same issue. Here's what worked for me. Shortly, you should put your code in `ngAfterViewInit()` instead of `constructor()`

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.loadMap();
  });
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use this tutorial here from [josh morony](https://www.joshmorony.com/getting-started-with-google-maps-in-ionic-2/) it has all information needed on adding google maps in ionic 2